# In the mechanism of Cannizzaro reaction, how do we rationalize hydrogen acting as leaving group?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

> [image]
> Mechanism of Cannizzaro from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannizzaro_reaction#Mechanism)

I am trying to understand how to rationalize in the first step of third row that the hydrogen act as a leaving group and a nucleophile. After googling, I found this [quora post](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-hydrogen-act-as-a-leaving-group-in-Cannizzaro-reactions-if-the-hydride-anion-is-a-very-strong-base), from which the only notable information I gathered was this following paragraph

> It is unlikely that the hydride ion being transferred in step two is actually a discrete separated hydride ion H- floating around in solution. Rather it is just an H- sliding across from one carbon atom to another, without every becoming completely detached. This will require a high concentration of the starting materials so that they are close to each other.

I can understand the above, but still how would one rationalize hydrogen , a poor leaving group, acting as a leaving group in the above scheme?

Comment: This paper asked the same question as well :D https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1985/p2/p29850000717#!divAbstract

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/25202/cannizaro-reaction-hydride-shift-reason